# Importing firebase in node.js for cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was following a tutorial for writing cloud functions, i tried to import firebase and use firebase.auth() as used in tutorial, but i am getting the below error.

```
⚠  Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /home/sankethbk7777/Desktop/React/Projects/social-ape/my-code/social-ape/functions/node_modules/firebase/package.json
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:299:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:522:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:449:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:489:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sankethbk7777/Desktop/React/Projects/social-ape/my-code/social-ape/functions/index.js:19:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
⚠  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
```

code

functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = require('express')();

admin.initializeApp();

const config = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDMFe1IwnLoui-Meue-FMwNhc1k-MB8vc8',
  authDomain: 'socialape-d306c.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'socialape-d306c',
  storageBucket: 'socialape-d306c.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '705972174784',
  appId: '1:705972174784:web:1ed87302a774bd1cef1225',
};

const firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Signup route

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle,
  };
  // TODO: validate date

  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then((data) => {
      return res
        .status(201)
        .json({ message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully` });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
});

// To tell firebase cloud functions to use routes on express app
// we have written api because we want all our API URL's to start with /api.

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I know import could be little different because of version change (the tutorial is from 2019) but i am not able to fix it. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the *Admin SDK* in a Cloud function and not the client. That being said you can remove the `const firebase = require("firebase")` and `firebase.initializeApp(config);` along with the *client configuration*. To create users, you can use the [`createUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) method:

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle,
  };

  return admin.auth().createUser({ email, password }).then((userRecord) => {
    return res.send(`Created user ${userRecord.uid}`)
  })
}
```

I am not sure what the 'handle' is but you can use [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) or any database to store it.

Do note that creating users in a Cloud function or a server environment won't log the user in automatically. You must redirect users to your login page after returning the response.